# Sonata admin: user_block is not displayed

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm using SonataAdmin and I can't see the user block displayed in the template (on the top right) although I have replaced it with my custom template as mentioned in the configuration here https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/templates.html
I'm using SonataUserBundle and this is my configuration:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        user_block: ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Default:user_block.html.twig
```

and these are the versions I'm using:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.43",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.7",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "4.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
```

I get no error however the user icon on the top right is not displayed !
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so I found that sonata is testing if the user has `role_admin` to display the `user_block` as mentioned here https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig#L194 
look for this condition:

```
{% if app.user and is_granted(sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('role_admin')) %}
```

and since all users has the role `ROLE_USER` I just need to give this information to sonata, in the **config.yml** file, so it will display the `user_block` to all connected users, like so:

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        role_admin: ROLE_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        role_admin: foobar_token


class UserBlockVoter extends Voter
{
    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        return 'foobar_token' == $attribute;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

if changing roles is not the case - create a voter for custom-named "role_admin" attribute, since decision of showing/hiding is based on security checker.

furthermore, you could check "User" instance inside voter with more complex rules than just "ROLE_ADMIN"